# Enabling VLAs (variable length arrays) in MS Visual C++?

Tags: c, visual-c++, c99, c89, variable-length-array

How can I enable the use of VLAs, variable length arrays as defined in C99, in MS Visual C++ or that is not possible at all?

Yes I know that the C++ standard is based on C89 and that VLAs are not available in C89 standard and thus aren't available in C++, but MSVC++ is supposed to be a C compiler also, a behavior that can be switched on using the /TC compiler parameter (`Compile as C Code (/TC)`). But doing so does not seem to enable VLAs and the compiling process fails with the same errors when building as C++ (`Compile as C++ Code (/TP)`). Maybe MSVC++ C compiler is C89 compliant only or I am missing something (some special construct or pragma/define)?

Code sample:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char pc[argc+5];

  /* do something useful with pc */

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile errors:

> error C2057: expected constant expression
>
> error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
>
> error C2133: 'pc' : unknown size

Comment: C++ users should use a `std::vector` instead of a VLA. The advice does not help this question due to the C requirement, however.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

MSVC is not a C99 compiler, and does not support variable length arrays.

At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/ansi-conformance MSVC is documented as conforming to C90.

Comment: Not only that, it probably never will: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/333273/request-for-c99-vla-in-visual-studio  Too bad.

Comment: That settles the dispute then. :-) Is there a Microsoft extension to the language that enables VLAs? GCC has one, thus enabling them for C90 and C++, besides C99 compliance. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: I think the link John provided indicates that there isn't, and won't be any time soon.

Comment: That feedback is from 2008, but that's probably the case for today also. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: There is no support for VLAs. MS suggest you use the C++ mode of the compiler, with std::vector as a replacement for VLAs.

Comment: Just to add that yes, as of MSVS 2015, MS will only support C99 features that are also required by C++11.  At this point it's settled.

Comment: What's stupid about this is, those of us who have actually written identical data structures that are FASTER than std::vector need VLAs (responsibly used) in our implementations. Oh well, back to not supporting MSVC. Their loss, I suppose.

Answer (score 9):

VLA's are much neater to write but you can get similar behaviour using `alloca()` when the dynamic memory allocation of `std::vector` is prohibitive.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9sx5da1.aspx

Using `alloca()` in your example would give:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <alloca.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char* pc = (char*) alloca(sizeof(char) * (argc+5));

  /* do something useful with pc */

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Both `alloca` and its friend `_alloca` are deprecated in favor of `_malloca` in newer versions of msvc. And that function is so annoying to use that it is better to just declare an array of constant length and use that.

Comment: dont you have to free memory allocated by alloca ?

Comment: @HaSeeBMiR No. As the memory allocated by alloca() is on the stack it is automatically reclaimed when the stack is unwound. See the documentation for your version for specifics.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: What do you find annoying about `_malloca()`?  Explicitly calling `_freea()` will allow easy substitution of other allocation methods should the need arise, and being able to call `_freea()` in the middle of a function seems much more useful than not having any means of releasing storage before a function exits.

Comment: The main reason for using `alloca` is because stack memory is faster than heap memory. But `_malloca` isn't guaranteed to return stack memory meaning unpredictable performance in hard-to-debug edge cases when the stack is almost full. In these scenarios, you'll get impossible to debug memory leaks that doesn't otherwise happen when you forget to free the allocated memory. No tools like valgrind can help, because 99% of the time the memory is taken from the stack so the leak isn't there! Imagine debugging a memleak that only occurs on some machines because they have a smaller stack size...

Answer (score 6):

I met same problem, this is not possible in MS Visual C++ 2015, instead you can use vector to do almost the same, only difference is neglectable overhead of heap resource manage routine(new/delete).

Although VLAs is convenient, but to allocate non-deterministic amount of memory from the stack at risk of stack overflow is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC 2015 does not support C99.
Use this logic using dynamic memory allocation instead..

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* pc = (char*)malloc((argc + 5) * sizeof(char));

    /* do something useful with pc */
    
    free(pc);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

To create a variable length array using c++, using your example, you would do something like the following:

```
size_t size = argc + 5;
vector<char> pc(size);
```

If you wanted to convert it over to std:string:

```
string buffer(pc.begin(), pc.end());
```

Comment: This is tagged C. Answers about other programming languages are off-topic and unhelpful.

Comment: +1 The question _is_ tagged visual-c++. And in the same situation it gave me the idea to avoid use of "new char[size]" for a VLA in a function with multiple returns... vector<char> vbuf(size); char *buf = & * vbuf.begin();"