# shouldn't dynamically allocating the size of a C array give an error ?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic, static

```
int n=10;
int arr[n];
```

this code works fine in my GCC compiler. Isn't the size of static array is allocated at compilation time ? Shouldn't this code generate an error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable length arrays are a `C99` feature(optional in `C11`) and `gcc` supports this as an [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) when not in `c99` mode, one quick way to see this with `gcc` is to use the following:

```
gcc -std=c89 -pedantic
```

You will see the following warning:

```
warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘arr’ [-Wvla]
```

but if you build using `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` you will not see any warnings. From the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.5.2` *Array declarators paragraph 4*:

> [...] If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.

Comment: For the sake of completeness. Visual C++ only supports C89 (which disallows dynamically-sized arrays), and C++ standards (none of which allows dynamically-sized arrays). So, if you use this feature, your code will be unsupported by Microsoft C compiler (it can still be compiled on Windows with MinGW).

Comment: @GiulioFranco Actually, until [recently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17914975/1708801) VS did not support `C99`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour this kind of progress is always nice, but unfortunately the article linked by the answer you linked says nothing about dyna-size arrays (it only speaks about library functions). I don't currently have VS2013 (has it even been released yet?) so I can't try. Besides, Microsoft documentation on C syntax still says "constant-expression".
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5eay31s2.aspx