# Significance of 'u' after integer value in array declaration

Tags: c, arrays, syntax

I'm sure this has a very simple answer, but it is a difficult question to search for:

What is the significance (necessity?) of adding a 'u' after an integer in C.

Example:

```
unsigned char Buffer1[2048];
unsigned char Buffer2[2048u];
```

Would anyone be kind enough to explain the importance of the 'u'?

I appreciate the help,

**Edit:**  In addition to 'what' the 'u' stands for, I would like a better understanding of 'why' you would need to use it.

Again, thank you for your input,

Comment: Do you have more context to this question? Is the code you are asking about exactly like you posted? It is not apparent from your example that it makes a difference, the standard requires that the size be an integer and greater than zero.

Comment: Shafik - yes, here is my context:  I have encountered this suffix for the first time in a function I am editing.  I will be altering the buffer size through a parameter instead of a constant, and I am not clear why the 'u' was added in my case.  I'd like to better understand 'why' one would need to use it.  Thanks for your input,

Comment: SBI - yes, that question is close to what I'm asking for.  But I guess specifically for the C language, I am still not seeing when it would be necessary to use this casting...

Comment: If the code looks like what you provided then I don't see any difference, be aware that using a variable for the array size will be using [variable length arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521398/which-compiler-should-i-trust), so the code won't work in all compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes the integer literal unsigned: `2048` is a (signed) `int`, `2048u` is an `unsigned int`.

Likewise, `l` or `L` makes it a `long` instead of an `int`, and `ul` or `UL` makes it an `unsigned long`.

(Note: Please use `L` rather than `l` because the lower-case `l` can be easily confused with the digit `1`).

Answer (score 2):

What you write as `2048` is an integer literal of type `int`. By adding an `u` after it, you signify the *type* to be `unsigned int`, not merely `int`.