# Hackly mix C/C++ syntax in single file?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, c99

I am assigned to port a big project from a dialect of `C99` to `Visual C++ 2013`.

The dialect of `C99`:

1. When `C99` and `C++` have different behaviors, choose C++.
2. Supports some `C++`  features, e.g. function/operator overloading.
3. Supports some `C99` features, e.g. compound literals, variadic macros, and designated initializer.

Before getting stuck, I wanna know if we can write `C99/C++` mixed code in `VS2013`?

It must be compiled on both compilers, I guess there might be some amazing pragmas like

```
 struct T {
     int data;
 };
 #pragma CompiledByC99_begin
 struct T tmp = { .data = 1 };
 #pragma CompiledByC99_end
```

Unfortunately, nothing found after Googling. Does such hack exist in `VS2013`?

Comment: I dont know if you can really do this with vs, I would go with CMake (supported by vs), take a look over it, you can modify the build behaviour with it as you need

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make sense, because you certainly don't want `.data` to be initialized to `1` in one compiler, and uninitialized in the other one. What you *can* do is define certain macros depending on the compiler, which is basically the standard way for cross-compiler support. This also includes compiler-specific keywords (like `far` or `near` for embedded firmware programming). Projects sometimes even define their own entire sets of defines for all primitive types (like `U08`, `S08`, `U16` for `byte`, `signed byte` or `signed short`). Btw, why not VS2015 community edition?

Comment: Define what you mean by porting... Are you expected to rewrite genuine C++11 to replace C99 code? Also, did you try to compile your C99 code with your C++11 compiler? Then, what concrete issues did you encounter (be specific, e.g. give compiler errors)? So **edit your question** to improve it, it is currently unclear.

Comment: If I am trying to read between the lines, project was compiled with C++ compiler which supported some of C99 features as an extension?  Because C99 compiler that supports funciton/operator overloading sounds horrible. What compiler were you using originally?

Comment: This looks like a case where the introduction of a few macro's may reduce the clutter quite a bit. But stuff like the ` = { .data = 1 }` should just be rewritten as a normal initialization followed by member assignment.

Comment: IMHO: Don't mix, make it standard compliant C++ (C++11 or even C++14, though both will probably be hard with VS2013) for as much as you can, compile these parts with a (standard compliant) C++ compiler, and compile the rest with the compiler handling your "C99 dialect", then link everything together. This will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change some small portions of code to make them compilable by MSVC2013, you can use the `_MSC_VER`. It is defined for MSVC compilers and has integer value 1800 for VC 2013.

So you can use

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
// code compilable under MSVC
#else
// other dialect
#endif
```

([Refs on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.120%29.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

You can only use a limited selection of C99 features in Visual Studio 2015 and even less in 2013 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826409/what-is-the-official-status-of-c99-support-in-vs2013) for reference)

Quote from [MSDN Blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/06/28/c1114-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013/) related to your needed features:

> Additionally, some C99 Core Language features will be implemented in
> 2013 RTM:
>
> C99 _Bool
>
> C99 compound literals
>
> C99 designated initializers
>
> C99
> variable declarations

So, depending on what exactly you need, you may be able to do it without any hack