# Why isn't my data protected even if I use "const" in C?

Tags: c, arrays, constants

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    const int marbles[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    int *ptr = marbles;
    *ptr = 100;
    printf("%d \n", marbles[0]); // output is "100"

}
```

I used `const` to protect the array. So I thought `int *ptr = marbles` would cause error. Otherwise by using pointer, it would enable user to change the data in the array. But surprisingly the output is "100". Isn't C suppose to protect the array from any kind of methods when I use `const`?

Comment: Isn't it enough that the compiler utters a warning?

Comment: `int *ptr = marbles;` broke the contract.  Change to `const int *ptr = marbles;`

Comment: the assignment of `marbles` to `ptr` is an incompatible pointer assignment as it discards the `const` qualifier and violates the C standard, but most compilers issue a warning using default settings to avoid breaking legacy builds

Comment: C does not protect you from mistakes, it just manages the best it could. Compile the code with warnings enabled to enable the errors. I think the correct warning is `-Wno-pointer-sign`

Comment: GCC complains (warning or error) about: `error: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror=discarded-qualifiers]` for the line
     `int *ptr = marbles;` — so it doesn't compile cleanly.  Pay heed to your compiler.  If it didn't warn you, turn up the warning levels, or get a better compiler.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi  Oh I see.. But I expected an error message, not a warning message. That's what confused me!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm using visual studio 2015. Should I get another compiler?

Comment: @jwqwerty: I decline to answer that question — this is meant to be a family show.  What warning level were you using?  ISTR `/W3` or thereabouts being fairly fussy; was there a `/W4`?

Comment: @jwqwerty visual studio has a **very** poor support of the C standard, to put it politely, and they do not plan to change that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It gave me warning C4090. Guess that's /W4?

Comment: Pass: I've not used a Visual Studio compiler in anguish in the current decade — I am not au fait with its current error messages.  I am mildly amazed I remember the `/Wn` options.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I should use another compiler! BTW which compiler are you using?

Comment: Note that if the array is global, then you probably get a runtime error.  The initialized data is probably placed in read-only memory (as part of the text segment, in Unix parlance), and the attempted assignment leads to a crash.  This was tested on Mac OS X; I can't be sure what would happen with MSVC.  The local (stack-based) array can't readily be given that much protection.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: Really? Last time I checked Visual Studio had excellent support for C standard and they were rapidly improving it from version to version. Which is exact opposite of your claim. So what are you talking about?

Comment: @AnT Now I'm confused...

Comment: @jwqwerty: Why? Traditionally, C compilers issue "a mere warning" for this kind of violation (all of them, not just Visual Studio). You just need to understand that "warning" can easily stand for an "error".

Comment: @AnT they aim to support C90 but [that's it](https://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/). "*the C standard*" is a little vague, so maybe he means the modern standards.

Comment: @Ryan Haining: Absolutely wrong. The page you linked became obsolete many years ago. Visual Studio committed to C99 support several versions ago, and by now they have already implemented full support for C99 (with few minor exceptions, like [now optional] VLA and slightly non-compliant `restrict`,although I haven't tested the latest update).

Comment: @AnT Okay. So I guess it's safe to use visual studio 2015?

Comment: @AnT source? I'm sure they added whatever was new to C++11/14 to their C mode but I can't find anything they have C99 support.

Comment: @Ryan Haining: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826409/what-is-the-official-status-of-c99-support-in-vs2013. Another source: just try it.

Comment: @AnT [splendid!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/06/28/c1114-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013/) I don't have any windows computers in my life anymore with which to try it, just online compilers.

Comment: @AnT  Yep, VLA is not working on latest version of Visual Studio 2015. BTW do you know whether VS is planning to support VLA?

Comment: @AnT if "standard" is not specified it's the current one and the current one is ISO/IEC 9899-2011, a five year old standard. If such a large IT-company like Microsoft does not support a current IT-standard after 5 years we can safely assume that they do not want to do so in the near future, if at all. That's a business decision. I don't have MS-shares, so I don't care. There are several free C-compilers for Windows and if you develop for Intel hardware you can use their compiler (I think they have a free version, too, but I'm not sure) which has commercial support.

Answer (score 3):

When I tried to compile the program, it showed this warning. So I guess when you initialize the pointer, `const` keyword loses its effect.

```
In function ‘main’:
try.c:6:16: warning: **initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer** target type [enabled by default]
     int *ptr = marbles;
```

Answer (score 2):

> So I thought `int *ptr = marbles` would cause error.

It is an "error". C language considers this initialization a *constraint violation*, which is what we typically call an "error".

The compiler is required to issue a diagnostic message in response to a *constraint violation*, which is exactly what it did in your case.

Typically, it is your responsibility to analyze diagnostic message issued by your compiler and figure out which are "innocent" and which indicate serious errors.