# How to declare a variable length array in Visual Studio C89 following other code

Tags: c, arrays, c99, c89, variable-length-array

I understand in VS all variables must be declared at the top of a block, but if I want a VLA, ie. if I wanted to do something like this:

```
int result = runalgorithm(); 

int vla[result];
```

the code above is invalid, because `vla` must be declared at the top. What is a good solution for this, other than creating an arbitrarily large array?

Comment: `int* vla = malloc ( result * sizeof *vla);` and after its use, `free(vla)`

Comment: Visual Studio in the past [did not support VLA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18521398/1708801) and as far as I know still does not.

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour: Thankfully it does support [_alloca](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx) which serves much the same purpose.

Comment: thank you cool guy. this should work to solve my issue.

Comment: I think this feature is very bad practice. Use `malloc` all times or don't use C language.

Comment: @i486 IMHO, you should mention that is your _personal opinion_. There is nothing _inherently_ wrong trying to use VLA.

Comment: C89/C90 requires a block to contain a sequence of declarations followed by a sequence of statements. C99 relaxes that requirement and permits declarations and statements to be mixed. Both lines of code in your question are declarations, so they don't violate the C89/C90 restriction. The problem is that C89/C90 doesn't support VLAs.

Comment: @Natasha Dutta - You can see "I think" in my comment. What does it mean? Maybe you have little knowledge of C or other programming languages when you cannot understand my opinion.

Comment: @i486 I don't know how, but maybe I just missed the "I Think" part. Are you sure you did not edit that comment later?(Just asking, no offense). Sorry. No need to be rude for that. An "ad hominem" is really not necessary here.

Comment: Comment is not edited later.

Comment: "I understand in VS all variables must be declared at the top of a block". That's simply false. Starting from Visual Studio 2013, VS supports C99-style variable declarations, meaning that variable declarations do not have to be at the top of the block.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) is supported in `C99` and later standards.  (Support is mandatory in C99; it is optional in C11.) `C89` does not have the VLA concept or support for it.

You can choose dynamic memory allocation, instead. have a look at [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family for your reference.

Remember, if you want to use dynamic memory (allocation), you have to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) the allocated memory once you're done using it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. malloc should work for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC doesn't support VLAs.  Recent versions of MSVC do support declarations mixed with statements in C compiles (I think this started with VS 2013).