# Array with variable size in C in VS

Tags: c, arrays, static

Under GCC 4.8.1

```
static int len = 10;
int main() {
    int a[len];
    return 0;
}
```

can compile success.

But compile will fail if changed like this:

```
static int len = 10;
int main() {
    static int a[len];
    return 0;
}
```

But in my Visual Studio, the former also can not compile success. How can I fix this problem?
And is there a way to change latter one to make it compile success?

Comment: If you want to use Visual Studio, the obvious fix is to replace the VLAs by pointers and explicitly malloc the memory. In C99 they are really a rather minor conviencence and are easy enough to live without.

Comment: @JohnColeman You're right, but I disagree with VLAs being "a minor convenience". In most implementations, they're segfaults waiting to happen, because they're essentially uncontrollable calls to `alloca()`.

Comment: @Rhymoid Is that why C11 took a step back from them?

Comment: @JohnColeman I don't know. The C11 rationale hasn't been published yet. Hurray, standards organisations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSVC compiler only supports C90, it does not support C99, and variable length arrays are a feature of C99.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246900/enabling-vlasvariable-length-arrays-in-ms-visual-c); it's not possible even with MSVC++.

Answer (score 0):

The MSVC on windows does not support VLAs yet, so you will need to make the array with dynamic memory allocation:

```
static int len = 10;
int main() {
    int *a = malloc(len * sizeof(int));
    if (a == NULL) exit(1);
    return 0;
}
```