# Variable-Length Arrays in c programming

Tags: c, arrays, variable-length-array

I want to create an variable-length array.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int n,i, response;
    while(true){
        printf("Enter the number of responses:");
        scanf("%i",&n);
        if(n<1){
            printf("Wrong number\n");
        }
        else
            break;
    } 
    int raiting[n];
}
```

Here I assign the value, that user enter, to the variable `n` and the value should be greater than one.

But it give me errors:

1)expected constant expression

2)cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

3)'raiting unknown size'

I am using Visual Studio.

How can I fix that? Why it's wrong?

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what compiler flags are you passing it? VLAs require C99 support.

Comment: "expected constant expression" --> Using a C++ compiler?

Comment: Normally, when one wants a variable-sized array, they allocate memory for it on the heap with `malloc`.

Comment: @interjay
I am using Visual Studio. So, the problem is in compiler?
Everything is ok with code?

Comment: @chux
I am using visual studio 2015.

Comment: @ForceBru `malloc()` does not provide an _array_, but a pointer to memory.  Although similar, there are differences.  See C11 6.7.6.2 2 Array declarators.

Comment: @interjay: **at least** C99. C11 also supports them (they have been made optional, though).

Comment: visual studio 2015 incorporates a number of tools and compilers.  Are you using a C++ compiler or a C compiler within visual studio 2015?

Comment: @chux, this is why I said `malloc` _allocates memory_ for data.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't support a lot of C99. I don't think it has VLAs.

Comment: MSVC is not standard compliant and never has supported C99. Get a modern compiler like gcc or clang which **are** standard compliant. Note this does not only apply to VLAs, but also other modern features of C which are introduced with C99.

Comment: @Olaf
Thank you! Which compiler would you advice: gcc or clang?

Comment: I'm fine with gcc, but actually don't use clang, so far. For standard code both should be fine.

Comment: @ForceBru OP clearly wants a variable length array, VLA, which has a specific meaning in C.

Comment: Sidenote: check for `n <= 0` to avoid a zero-length array (valid, but nonsense).

Comment: This question was answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246900/enabling-vlasvariable-length-arrays-in-ms-visual-c. The bottom line: MSVC is not C99 compliant and doesn't support VLAs. I tried to suggest an alternative, but for whatever reason you did not like it.