# Very simple program compiles in Dev C++ but not in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I made this very simple program:

```
   int a;
   scanf("%i", &a);
   int tab[a];
```

And there there is the rest of program which works fine when I compile in DevC++. But when I use this:

```
   int a;
   scanf_s("%i", &a);
   int tab[a];
```

in Visual Studio 2015 there is a error. I have no idea whats wrong with that.

Comment: There are no VLAs in Visual Studio. If you really need this, you can use `int *tab = alloca(a * sizeof(*tab)` instead of `int tab[a];`. Don't forget `#include <malloc.h>  `

Comment: VLA => Variable Length Array

Comment: So how can i declare length of tab from keyboard? I mean by scanf_s

Comment: @Finer by doing what I suggested in the first comment.

Comment: @Finer There's another aspect to consider here as well: This was tagged as a "C" question, but depending on the C standard you're dealing with, what you're compiling successfully in Dev C++ may only be valid by virtue of extension; see [Variable declaration placement in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/288441/6610379).  If it's optional to compile as "C" (and you could just as well work in C++), you'll have some other possibilities.

Comment: What error did you get from VS2015?

Answer (score 1):

Variable Length Arrays (VLA) are part of the C99 Standard, but not part of the C++11/C++14 Standard so they are not implemented by the Visual C++ compiler. As a "C" compiler, Visual C++ is C90 conformant with the portions of the C11 Standard Library that are required by reference in C++11.

> Note that the core of this question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246900/enabling-vlasvariable-length-arrays-in-ms-visual-c)