# Is there a VLAs (variable length arrays) support workaround for VS2017?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, visual-studio-2017, variable-length-array

So simple code like:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int s[n], p[2*(n-1)][3];
```

I have to translate to:

```
int  n;
cin >> n;
vector<int> s(n, 0);
vector<vector<int>> p(2 * (n - 1), vector<int>(3));
```

I would like to see something like:

```
int  n;
cin >> n;
mat s(n), p(2*(n-1), 3);
```

I definitely do not want to use `new\make_unique` and `std::array`+`std::vector` mix for such simple stuff. Two lines are an ugly mess IMHO so I seeek for a way to keep C like sintax.

So what is a workaround? Any define/standard header/copy-pastable STL based C++ type?

Comment: VLAs are not supported by C++ standard (but, are supported by extensions to some compilers, e.g.: g++).

Comment: Answer: There's no VLA in C++.

Comment: what is the problem with the second snippet? To me it is completely unclear what is the question

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246900/enabling-vlasvariable-length-arrays-in-ms-visual-c

Comment: I would personally make `p` a vector of arrays, like `std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> p(2 * (n - 1));`.

Comment: Regarding your updated title: "_Is there a VLAs (variable length arrays) support workaround for VS2017?_" If VLAs are not supported by C++ standard, why should any, one, compiler support it? If some provide extensions for such functionality, it doesn't matter that they (or any other compiler) have to.

Comment: Allocating huge arrays on the stack is not a good idea.

Comment: IMO the only workaround is the second piece of code in your question. What's wrong with it? If you think it's _"an ugly mess"_ then maybe C++ is not for you.

Comment: @Michael Walz:
Say you want to teach C++ to a kid. A kid can read simple code, kids tipically are a bit more confused with constructs like `vector<vector<int>> p(2 * (n - 1), vector<int>(3));` instead of `int p[2*(n-1)][3];` because long code boilerplate shadows/hides real logic. Even bigger problem arrives when they can use ideone at home and VS2017 for school projects.

Comment: Use a matrix class like [this in Dr. Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/a-c-matrix-template-class/184403323) or write your own.

Comment: OK, the question has actually totally changed with all your edits, mabe you should post an all new question about how to write `vector<vector<int>> p(2 * (n - 1), vector<int>(3));` like `mat p(2*(n-1), 3);`

Comment: @Michael: 1) isn't clarification what are edits for?) 2) it has not changed for me as inclusion of long external matrix class is a less preferable option to add some define for C support/stl include. There is some C support in VS2017, so why it is so hard for them to add this quite old feature is a mistary for me

Comment: @DuckQueen yes of course, but sometimes too many edits totally transform the question and you might get better exposure if you ask a new question about the _actual_ problem only. Not my downvote BTW.

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to keep C syntax in C++. Instead use C++ syntax.

Comment: @Xam: only when C++ syntax is in any way superior, here it just sucks=)

Answer (score 7):

Variable length arrays are not supported by standard C++.

`std::vector<int>` is the idiomatic way of implementing a contiguous block of `int` data whose size is not known at compile time. A good rule of thumb is to use `std::vector` until you find a compelling reason not to.

Answer (score 5):

Variable length arrays (i.e. arrays where at least one dimension is not a compile time constant) are not supported in standard C++. Hence, you cannot write something like `cin >> n; int s[n]`.
Some extensions exist, but still - for very large values of `n`, you might get troubles if the compiler at hand puts such an array on the "stack", which is usually more limited than the heap.

The standard way is to use `std::vector<int> s(n)` or, if - though usually not recommended - for some reason you want a "plain" array not wrapped by an object, you could write `int *s = new int[n];`, although it is then incumbent on you calling `delete[] s;` when you no longer need the array.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my aggressive edit. Do rollback if you don't like it. +1 btw.

Answer (score 2):

alloca is another alternative. Not standard but widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

By standard C++, there's no Variable Length Arrays (VLAs). Either use an STL like `std::vector`, or define the variables as `const` (that you can't modify at runtime).