# Compile Error C2131 and C3863 on Windows but NOT on Linux

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a piece of code that compiles and works fine on Linux (Raspbian) but doesn't compile on windows (VS 17).

I am using CMAKE 3 for cross platform compiling, and like I said, I have no problem building this on Linux.

Here are the only CMAKE options that I am using:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(Track)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
...
// The rest of the CMakeLists.txt has nothing fancy
```

But under windows (using VS 17 native compiler), there is a piece of code which doesnt even build and I don't get why. The error that I get is (sorry it is in french but pretty understandable I think):

```
error C2131: l'expression n'a pas été évaluée en constante    
note: échec en raison de l'appel d'une fonction indéfinie ou 'constexpr' non déclarée
note: voir l'utilisation de 'std::vector<ROI,std::allocator<_Ty>>::size'
error C3863: le type de tableau 'float ['fonction'+]['fonction'+]' n'est pas attribuable
```

And the (simplified) piece of code causing the error :

```
// Defined somewhere else
class ROI
{
}

class Tracker
{
public:
    void UpdateTrack(vector<ROI> new_roi)
    {
        // some code
        float match_table[new_roi.size() + 1][m_tracked_roi.size() + 1];  // COMPILE ERROR
        // some code
    }

private:
    vector<ROI> m_tracked_roi;
}
```

I think the problem is about the size of the array being known only at compile time or something like that, but it is possible with c++ now, and it works fine on Linux (by working I mean it builds and runs fine).

Can someone explain me what's goind on? and how to fix this on windows?  (probably some additional CMake options?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling VLAs (variable length arrays) in MS Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5246900/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable length arrays are not part of standard C++.  Array bounds must be compile-time constant expressions.

GCC and Clang both provide VLAs as an extension, but VisualStudio does not.  Use `std::vector` if you need a cross-platform non-constant length array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That means that GCC and Clang are smarter compiler than VS ? Isn't this a bit of a shame?

I know about std::vector (I use them all the time), but it is kind of a pain to declare 2D arrays with std::vectors.

Comment: No, it means that they implement a feature that is not part of the C++ language.

Comment: Is compile-time size arrays possible using std::array ?

Comment: `std::array`'s bound must be a compile-time constant just like a raw array.  Its `size` method is `constexpr`, and so it is a valid compile-time constant expression for use in declaring another array (be that a `std::array` or a raw array).

Comment: I have read that VLA were in C99. WHat is going on with VS?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  VLAs are part of C, but they are not part of C++.