# Why does array allocation with a variable work?

Tags: c, arrays, variable-length-array

This code:

```
int main() {
   int size;
   scanf("%d", &size);
   int array[size]; 
}
```

works fine with GCC, but VC expects a constant expression for the size of the array so does not compile it (which makes more sense to me). Any idea why it works with GCC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling VLAs (variable length arrays) in MS Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246900/enabling-vlas-variable-length-arrays-in-ms-visual-c)

Comment: It's one of the more inscrutable bits of the standard, but C11 [§6.7.6.2 Array Declarators ¶4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p4) defines variable length arrays.  Just for once, this isn't a GCC extension.

Comment: Try adding `printf("%d",size);` just after the line `int size;`. I'm not sure, maybe it's because of the garbage value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because gcc supports [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

It was added as a part of C99 standard, however, in the later standards (C11 and C18), it's an optional feature.

Comment: You might add a note that VC only supports c90.

Comment: @JL2210 : ... plus those parts of C11 that are also valid C++ (but not VLAs because they are not).

Answer (score 0):

Because variable-length arrays (VLAs) are neither valid in C90 nor C++11 MSVC does not support them:

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=vs-2019:(

> The C compiler is an C89/C90 compiler that, by default, enables
>   Microsoft extensions to the C language.

VLAs may be best avoided in any event because a C11 compiler need not implement them and they are potentially unsafe.  Typically an implementation will allocate VLAs on the stack.  In your code, it only takes a user to enter an arbitrarily large value to break your code in someone-deterministic manner - any use of VLAs should have some constraint test to ensure the length is reasonable and in the capability of the system to support.