# Is there a way to enable support for C99 variable length arrays in microsoft visual studio. If No, what is the best alternative?

Tags: c

The following code wont compile. It give me an error that 'a constant size was expected'.
Is there any way or a compiler flag or a preprocessor directive to add, to cause enable support for C99 features such as the VLAs.

```c
#include "Window.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
   const int size = 1024 ;
   char filename[size]; 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling VLAs (variable length arrays) in MS Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246900/enabling-vlas-variable-length-arrays-in-ms-visual-c)

Comment: Probably depends on which version of the compiler you have. They made some half-hearted attempt to partially support C99 couple of years ago. Or if your question is what's the best alternative to VC, then pretty much any random C compiler made this millennium is better.

Comment: What kind of alternative are you looking for? MinGW?

Comment: Note that VLAs became optional in C11 (implementation must define the macro `__STDC_NO_VLA__` to be `1` in that case).

Comment: Use a macro instead of a variable: `#define SIZE 1024` ... `filename[SIZE];`

Comment: AFAIK, you could keep the IDE, but change the compiler, see e.g. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/ or https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-mingw-and-cygwin-with-visual-cpp-and-open-folder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already outlined in comments, your (obvious) options with C+MSVC would be:

1. A macro (you can `#undef` it when no longer needed)
2. alloca (shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18198845/5578773)), which allocates on stack and does not require explicit deallocation; you may wrap it in a macro for a convenient "create X-sized array of Y" pseudo-function

As it [was answered](http://web.archive.org/web/20140205183758/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/333273/request-for-c99-vla-in-visual-studio) on now-dead Microsoft Connect, MSVC does not support C99 VLAs as such, which likely didn't change since then.