# Unable to scan size into array

Tags: c

```
int n;
printf("How many?");
scanf("%d", &n);

int array[n];
```

These are the errors I get..
error C2057: expected constant expression
error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
error C2133: 'array': unknown size

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please state which compiler you are using. Looks like a Microsoft compiler - those do not support Variable Length Arrays (VLAs).

Comment: Looks like Visual Studio which does not support VLA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling VLAs (variable length arrays) in MS Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246900/enabling-vlas-variable-length-arrays-in-ms-visual-c)

Comment: C99? Otherwise  int *array = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

Comment: Yes, it's visual studio. Using malloc worked. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some compilers don't support variable-length array and unfortunately your compiler seems one of them.

You can use `malloc()` from `stdlib.h` to allocate arrays dynamically.

```
int n;
printf("How many?");
scanf("%d", &n);

int* array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable length arrays require either:

1. C99
2. C11 and later with `_STDC_NO_VLA__` not defined.

---

Array sizes must be more than 0.

```
int n;
printf("How many?");
if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n > 0) {
  // Success
  int array[n];
  ...
}
```