# C++ Array Error: "variable-sized object may not be initialized"

Tags: c++, arrays

Any idea why this isn't working in C++? I feel like it's really simple, but I can't figure it out:

```
int main() {
  int arraySize = 5;
  char testArray[arraySize] = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
}
```

It works fine when I hard code 5 as the array size, but it doesn't like it when I use a variable name instead. Ultimately I'm trying to figure out how to write a function that deletes duplicate characters from the array, but I can't even get the array initialized.

Comment: Consider using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Does this answer your question? 
[Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: *Any idea why this isn't working in C++?* -- Because it isn't C++.

Comment: `const int arraySize = 5;` would make the code ok, but you really want a `std::vector<char>` or a `std::string`

Comment: char testArray[] = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'};` is all you need. The compiler will infer the size of the array from the number of elements in the initializer list.

Answer (score 2):

By default compilers are expecting mix of C++ and C code.
So VLA is enabled as an extension. It is possible to enfore pure C++ then this code will fail to compile.

Note that [msvc supports old C standard where VLA was not available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5246900/1387438) yet, so in many multi-platform projects compilers are configured not to use VLA.

Now this warning:

> variable-sized object may not be initialized

Basically says, you have requested VLA and you are initializing it with 5 elements.
It may happen that `arraySize` variable can be changed during runtime to value less then 5 and this can corrupt your initialization code. That is why this warning is reported. Some initialization may be uncompleted.

Now your question was closed as [duplicate indicating that C++ standard do not support VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/1387438). I reopened it since question was about warning what is not covered by duplicate.

Comment: VLA were only required in C99 and are an optional feature since C11...

Comment: @SergeBallesta didn't know that detail thanks.