# Problem with free in language C which doesn't work

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, free

I wrote this program and I want to free a structure `myStruct` but it doesn't compile it says:

> free():double free detected in tcache2

Can you help me please ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct myStruct {
    char* chaine;
    struct myStruct* next;
} mystruct;

void supprimer(myStruct* D) {
    free(D->chaine);
    free(D);
}

int main()
{
    myStruct* D = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
    D->next = NULL;
    char* chaine = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    chaine = "ouii";
    D->chaine = chaine;
    supprimer(D);
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to run the main with creating a new structure and deleting it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

`chaine = "ouii";` is wrong. That does not copy “ouii” into the memory pointed to by `chaine`, it sets the pointer `chaine` to point to the array created for the string literal `"ouii"`. That address should not be passed to `free`.

Change `chaine = "ouii";` to `strcpy(chaine, "ouii");`.

Comment: @lilo: Because the space for it was not allocated by `malloc` or a related routine. When you have a string literal in source code, the C implementation allocates space for its contents before the `main` routine starts.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* chaine = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    chaine = "ouii";
```

The second statement changes what `chaine` was originally pointing to (i.e. a pointer to a region of heap memory returned by `malloc`), such that it now points to the string literal `ouii`. Now you've lost access to the original memory returned by `malloc` (have leaked memory), and are trying to `free` memory not returned by one of the memory allocation functions. Hence the warning.

Possible fix:

- Use the standard `strcpy` to copy the strings.

  ```
   strcpy (chaine, "ouii");
  ```

  And add `#include <string.h>` to the list of headers.

---

Aside: `malloc` returns `NULL` on failure. You should check if the pointer is valid before accessing it. It also sets `errno` to `ENOMEM` on POSIX-compliant systems. Here's one way I prefer to handle it in `main ()`:

```
#include <errno.h>

errno = 0;
char *chaine = malloc (10); /* sizeof (char) is defined to be 1 */

if (!chaine) {
    errno = ENOMEM;
    perror ("malloc");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

---

See also: [How do I modify a char** in another function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75073005/20017547)

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet

```
char* chaine = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
chaine = "ouii";
```

results in a memory leak.

At first a memory was allocated dynamically and its address was assigned to the pointer `chaine`

```
char* chaine = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
```

and then the pointer was reassigned with the address of the first character of the string literal `"ouii"`

```
chaine = "ouii";
```

So the address of the dynamically allocated memory was lost.

Instead of this assignment

```
chaine = "ouii";
```

you need to copy characters of the string literal into the dynamically allocated memory using standard string function `strcpy` declared in the header `<string.h>`. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char* chaine = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
strcpy( chaine, "ouii" );
```

Pay attention to that this function

```
void supprimer(myStruct* D) {
    free(D->chaine);
    free(D);
}
```

makes the pointer `D` declared in main

```
myStruct* D = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
```

invalid.

It is better to pass the pointer to the function by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object (including pointers) indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the pointer you will have a direct access to the object pointed to by the pointer and can change it.

Also as it seems you want to define a singly linked list then the function can look the following way

```
void supprimer( myStruct **D ) 
{
    while ( *D != NULL )
    {
        myStruct *current = *D;
        *D = ( *D )->next;
        free( current->chaine );
        free( current );
    }
}
```

And the function is called like

```
supprimer( &D );
```

In this case after calling the function the pointer `D` defined in main will be equal to `NULL`.

Pay attention to that you should check whether memory was allocated successfully to avoid undefined behavior.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how your list could be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct myStruct
{
    char *chaine;
    struct myStruct *next;
} mystruct;

int push ( myStruct **D, const char *chaine )
{
    myStruct *current = malloc( sizeof( *current ) );
    int success = current != NULL;

    if (success)
    {
        current->chaine = malloc( strlen( chaine ) + 1 );
        success = current->chaine != NULL;

        if (success)
        {
            strcpy( current->chaine, chaine );
            current->next = *D;
            *D = current;
        }
        else
        {
            free( current );
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void supprimer( myStruct **D )
{
    while (*D != NULL)
    {
        myStruct *current = *D;
        *D = ( *D )->next;
        free( current->chaine );
        free( current );
    }
}

void output( const myStruct *D )
{
    for ( const myStruct *current = D; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" -> ", current->chaine );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main( void )
{
    myStruct *D = NULL;

    push( &D, "World" );
    push( &D, "Hello" );

    output( D );

    supprimer( &D );
}
```

The program output is

```
"Hello" -> "Word" -> null
```